# Code to load all images in an album in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to load **all** the images in an album in Facebook?  As soon as a person views the first image, the rest of the images should be automatically loaded in background.  How to do it?  Javascript? or any other language?

Answer (score 0):

yes there is, its a greasemonkey (javascript) add-on called Facebook Fixer. firstly download greasemonkey then the facebook fixer, then you have to enable it on the page you have the album on.
Reload the page, you should be able to see that there are new links at the top now, click "show big pictures" and there you have it.

Comment: I tried it, but I want to load the full images, not just the thumbnails. Any help?